# Error in if (x[i] > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, shapefile, r-maptools

I have this line in my code to create dots for a dot-density map. The function I'm misusing is dotsInPolys in the maptools package. I get this error when I run it and I'm not sure what it means. Can anyone help?

`NSWdots <- dotsInPolys(NSW, as.integer(datajoin$pop.10))`

NSW is a shapefile and datajoin$pop.10 is a vector of numbers.

The given error is:

`Error in if (x[i] > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your dataframe there are some `NA` values and you get the error.

Look what happens here:

```
 NA > 0 #this returns NA
[1] NA
```

If I use it in an `if` statement:

```
> if (NA > 0) print('Hello')
Error in if (NA > 0) print("Hello") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I get the same error as you.

In your case some instance of `x[i]` is `NA` and the above error is returned. You need to figure out a way to remove/deal with the `NA` values in your data.